# Button inside section element is rendered much larger

Tags: html, css

There is a ordered list and button inside a section element. Both the elements, list and button are placed inside a section element to place them in a single row. Browser makes the button larger to match the list's size. How to avoid it?

Also, button's `float: right` property is not floating the button to the right end.

[image]

Html code for the above image is,

```
<section>
<ol id="reports"><h3>Reports</h3>
<li>test_12345</li>
<li>test_1405114424964</li></ol>
<button style="float:right;">Execute Test      </button></section>
```

Css properties are,

```
section {
    display: flex;
}
button{
    clear: left;
    background-color:#699DB6;
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fycuadj/)

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle or something like that

Comment: It's because of display: flex

Comment: So.. do you want to resize your button right?

Comment: @Arnau, yes... i want button to be of it original smaller size

Comment: @Madhavan Kumar I updated an answer, tell me is it works or if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what you're really want to achieve, but if it's about floating list to the left, and button to the right, you need to start using couple more of flex properties. This could possibly go as here:

**HTML:**

```
<section>
    <ol id="reports">
        <h3>Reports</h3>

        <li>test_12345</li>
        <li>test_1405114424964</li>
    </ol>
    <button style="float:right;">Execute Test</button>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
section {
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: space-between;
}
button {
    clear: left;
    background-color:#699DB6;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 10px 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hedgehog34/3fycuadj/2/) for that.

As I said you need to be more precise of what you want to achieve here

Comment: Your welcome - now, go ahead and accept this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of display flex. Since your button is 37px height, you can add `max-height: 37px;`

Edit: Your fiddle updated : https://jsfiddle.net/3fycuadj/1/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle:

[New example](https://jsfiddle.net/3fycuadj/3/)

You just need this css. And you can also remove clear: left; I think it doesn't work.

```
button{
   clear: left;
   background-color:#699DB6;
   border-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   padding: 10px 30px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   float: right;
}
```

The problem was the propierty display: flex. Now the button is floating the right side.